# Facts not being updated

Tags: drools

I have the following 3 rules in my system.

Rule 1:

```
    when
        $x : MyObject1(name == "xxx")
    then
        $x.setValue("Y"); update($x);
end
```

Rule 2:

```
rule "rule_2"
    when
        p : P(data != 1)
        $t4 : MyObject1(name == "xxx", value == "Y")
    then
        p.setMessage("some message 1");
end
```

Rule 3:

```
    when
        p : P(data != 1)
        $t4 : MyObject1(name == "xxx", value == "N")
    then
        p.setMessage("some message 2");
end
```

Neither rule 2 or 3 are firing.  I would not expect rule 3 to fire because of the when clause but rule 2 should be firing.

It seems anytime I call `update` the rules are not re-run with the correct value.  Any ideas?
I have heard that updates are code smell but this is what I have and it has worked in past versions of drools.  I am using 7.73.0.Final

Comment: Likely the issue is with the `P` condition check, unless you're hitting a `retract` somewhere in a higher-salience rule. Unfortunately you've only given us snippets and not really explained what other sorts of rules are also present in this KieBase. `update` will reevaluate _all_ rules, as if you were firing the rules anew with new data, so there might be a rule elsewhere that's triggering on you.

Comment: You might consider hooking up a listener to your runtime and logging the rules as they hit so you can see what is being matched.

Comment: I do have a listener so I know it is not being hit and know what rules are hit.

Comment: What did find is if the line is changed to the following:
`$t4: MyObject(name = "xxx")`
`eval($t4.getValue() == "Y")`
then it evaluates to true and the rule fires

Comment: And to add to this... I am not calling `retract` anywhere.  The p condition check is not the issue.  If I just have the p condition it works fine.   There are over 100K other rules in the KieBase.  I can't show all of them.

Comment: Is that `name = "xxx"` a typo?

Comment: Yes.  It is a typo. Should be:  `$t4: MyObject(name == "xxx")`